# How get vscode eslint less verbose? (I only need the wavy underlines, not the detailed message)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I've been using vscode + eslint + prettier for react / react native editing. All of a sudden, it starts to show the detailed error / warning message, which is not necessary at all, after each wavy underline. The error / warning messages used to only show up when hovering over them.

All I need the classic wavy underlines and less verbosity. Please see the screenshot below. Thanks a lot!

[image: vscode screenshot]